# how to check the return value of mysql update statement in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I'm a novice java programmer and here is my code snippet to delete a record based on it's ID.

```
private void RemovebuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   

   BookIDvar=Integer.parseInt(BookID.getText());
   System.out.println(BookIDvar);
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  //STEP 3: Open a connection
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

  //STEP 4: Execute a query
  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  String sql;
  sql="DELETE FROM book_details WHERE book_id="+BookIDvar+"";
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
  //STEP 6: Clean-up environment

  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
 }
```

The code is working fine. But i want to check whether if there existed a record with that particular ID. Is there a way to check it using the current code itself? Does Java provide some constructs to check the return value of `executUpdate` similar to `executeQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

int a = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

System.out.println(a); // ---> Number of columns the query has manipulated in the database

### Syntax

**int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException**

Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

**Note** that the executeUpdate(); method return type is "int" i.e it returns the number of columns the query has manipulated in the database